# (JQuery) Use of word or phrase in textbox triggers action

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I currently have a working jQuery that looks for a certain phrase and trigger:

```
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function(){
    if($('#id_message').val().toLowerCase().indexOf('foo foo') > -1){
        doEgg();
    }
});
```

However I would love to be able to expand this to a list of words or phrases.  So have a separate list like this, which I assume need to be in an array?

```
var phraseList = [
    "foo foo",
    "foobar",
    "fooby foo foobar"
];
```

How can I get it to search a word list? I imagine the list only having maybe 5 phrases or so.  And if a user types "i like to foo foo" or "i love it at the foobar" it should still trigger as the textbox contains words from the list.

Also as an added problem, I have this script also which undoes the function if the user then decides to delete the phrase:

```
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function(){
    if($('#id_message').val().toLowerCase().indexOf('foo foo') == -1){
        undoEgg();
    }
});
```

EDIT #1

The closest answer I have found comes from @niXful-Autistic:

```
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function(){
    for(var i=0;i<phraseList.length;i++){
        if($('#id_message').val().toLowerCase().indexOf(phraseList[i]) > -1){
            doEgg();
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT #2

I believe I know where the problem is!

The value of .indexOf for the textbox is set up -1 as it works its way through the characters til it finds a word or phrase from the phraseList array...and then it assigns it a value which is > -1.

So whenever there is a keyup event, the value of indexOf is set initially to -1 until it can find one of the words of phrases.  So this causes the doEgg() and undoEgg() functions to be called and uncalled in quick succession repeatedly.

So I think I need a way to scan through the whole textbox before assigning an .indexOf value.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could simpy use `$.inArray()` to check the existense of a given value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function(){
  for(var i=0;i<phraseList.length;i++){
    if($('#id_message').val().toLowerCase().indexOf(phraseList[i]) > -1){
        doEgg();
    }
  }
});
```

*UPDATE*

I wish a suggestion

```js
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function(){
          for(var i=0;i<phraseList.length;i++){
            if($('#id_message').val().toLowerCase().indexOf(phraseList[i]) > -1){
                doEgg();
            }else{
                undoEgg(); 
            }
          }
});
```

*UPDATE* 2
Try to declare these variables outside the function

var change;
var changeback;

```
function doEgg(){
    if(changeback)clearInterval(changeback); //if changeback isRunning
    audioElement.play();
    //var change = setInterval(function () {
    change = setInterval(function () {
            ...
}

function undoEgg(){
    if(change)clearInterval(change); //if change isRunning
    audioElement.pause();
    //var changeback = setInterval(function () {
   changeback = setInterval(function () {
            ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @niXful-Autistic this works! However it has caused another bug for me when I want to undo the function.  I have edited my question slightly to explain. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @niXful-Autistic, the update seems to confuse the functions even more. Is there an alternative to keyup maybe?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your continued help @niXful-Autistic. however declaring those variables outside of the function has stopped it from working.  What could be the problem? I understand the theory...but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi @niXful-Autistic I have updated my question, I believe I have found where the problem lies.

Answer (score 4):

```
    $("#id_message").on('keyup', function () {
        phraseList.indexOf(this.value) > -1 ? //your code (i.e. doEgg()) :"";
    });
```

Comment: Remember, `indexOf` on `Array` doesn't work on <= IE8

Answer (score 1):

like this i guess:

```
var phraseList = [
    "foo foo",
    "foobar",
    "fooby foo foobar"
];
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function(){
    if(phraseList.indexOf(this.value) > -1){
        //doEgg();
        alert(phraseList[phraseList.indexOf(this.value)]); // alerts the matched string in the word list array.
    }
});
```

```js
var phraseList = [
  "foo foo",
  "foobar",
  "fooby foo foobar"
];
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function() {
  if (phraseList.indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
    alert(phraseList[phraseList.indexOf(this.value)]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='id_message'>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jai, this is really close, however it only works if the phrase contains no other text.  If the user enters "i like to foo foo" into the text box, even though they have mentioned "foo foo" the alert or function are not triggered.  How can I adapt your code to work?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) as below:

```
var phraseList = [
    "foo foo",
    "foobar",
    "fooby foo foobar"
];

if ( $.inArray("foo foo", phraseList) !== -1 ) {
    alert ("yes");
}
```

So, your code becomes:

```
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function() {
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if ( $.inArray(val, phraseList) !== -1 ) {
        doEgg();
    }
});
```

**Edit:** updated snippet based on your comment:

```
$("#id_message").on('keyup', function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $.each(phraseList, function(index, val) {
        if ( value.indexOf(val) !== -1 ) {
            doEgg();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ishettyl this is also really close, however it only works if I exclusively type the phrase from the phrase list.  What I would is for the phrase to be picked up even if someone types "i like to foo foo" for example, rather than when they only type "foo foo".

Comment: this has helped yes!  but the code still gets confused about which function to call it seems. is there a better less frequent way to call the function that isn't key up?

Comment: Hi @lshettyl, I believe I know where the problem lies. I have updated my question again

Comment: `keyup` triggers everytime a key is released which is very frequent, Try to use `change` and see if that helps.

Comment: I am not sure this will work lshettyl. I do want the functions to be called as the user is typing, rather than when they stop typing.  Is there a way to count all the characters, and then only calculate .indexOf once it has gotten to the last character? That way the functions should only run once the whole textbox has been checked for words or phrases included in the array.  Should I post this as a new question do you think? As my initial question has been answered.  Thanks again

Comment: A new question would make more sense as this question has been changed much from it's origin.